Android - App interface not updating/refreshing
I wrote an app with a simple button that changes color when I press it (example below).
If the power button of my phone is pressed the screen turns off.
If it is pressed again, the screen turns back on and I see my app again (screen lock is disabled).
I call this one cycle.
If this procedure is done once (one cycle), I can press the button in my app and it keeps changing the color with every push.
However, if I do the power button cycle twice or more times, the graphical interface/user interface/layout of my app is not updated anymore and the button remains in the color it was at before the power button was pressed.
What is confusing is that logcat still shows the AADEBUG messages. It is just not updating the color.
I have no experience with app programming.
Is there anything required such as refocusing/refreshing the app?
If I push the "App overview" button in the navigation bar and I chose my app from there it continues to keep working. Even after several power button cycles. It also works If I use a screen lock but I do not want to use it.
My real app is more complex but I was able to reproduce the issue even in this simple example. What am I missing?
package com.example.testapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var onetwo = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val testButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)

        testButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (onetwo == 0){
                Log.d("AADEBUG", "one")
                testButton.backgroundTintList = getColorStateList(R.color.white)
                onetwo = 1
            } else {
                Log.d("AADEBUG", "two")
                testButton.backgroundTintList = getColorStateList(R.color.purple_200)
                onetwo = 0
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("AAActivityState", "onResume called")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("AAActivityState", "onPause called")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}


Update
The app is supposed to run on a Sony Xperio XZ1 Compact with Android 9.
The screen lock is disabled.
My app is the only one running.
If I press the power button once, the display turns off.
If I press it again, the app is directly shown again because there is no screen lock present.
If I do this twice or more often, the layout/ui of the app does not get updated anymore but the app is responsive. If I play different sounds in addition to the button changing its color, the different sounds are played. But the color of the button does not change.
If I use swiping as a screen lock, everything works fine and the layout of the app is updated.
It just seems like the interface does not recover from the power button press if there is no screen lock or general updating of the user interface.
However, other standard apps on the phone are responsive in the same situation so it does not seem to be a general Android/Hardware issue.
Update 2
I recorded a video that demonstrates the behaviour:
https://streamable.com/wsf13c

As you mentioned, If it is pressed again, the screen turns back on and I see the my app again. But I cannot see any specific code where you have managed that?. I am unable to understand what you want to achieve here. Can you share more details or tell us what is the functionality you want to achieve

I updated my question with additional information at the bottom. There is no additional code besides what is shown and the layout for the single button. If you press the power button of a phone, it typically locks and the screen turns off. By pressing the power button again, the screen turns back on and I see my app straight away as there is no lock screen. However, if I do this more than once, the layout of my app becomes unresponsive.
